# How to link to external website from the app icons below the Timeline on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

How do you make those icon apps below your timeline so that when you click on one of them it opens a new window (or the same window) and goes to an external website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think you can do that. But, you can make it so that when you click them, they will go to the app page as normal, and in that app page you can put a javascript code to redirect that page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
top.window.location.replace('NEWLOCATION');
</script>
```

It will redirect the page (one which facebook is in)

Comment: I already knew that, but thanks anyway for replying, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the app you might be looking for

https://www.facebook.com/iframehost?sk=app_208195102528120